# Can you conserve momentum between two blocks when one of them is attached to a spring?

Tags: momentum, spring

[image]

I know that you can use conservation of momentum in these cases but I wanted to know why. The obvious answer was that the force exerted due to spring is negligible and can be neglected.

I wanted to know it is negligible to what?

This is what I came up with:

Both the bodies exert tremendous amount of force on each other and the force due to spring will just add a bit to it thus won't change much.
Besides, time of collision is very small i.e. $dt$. So, anything like F$dt$ will be finite only if F is some very large number (Here F represents force due to spring).

Now, why wouldn't the force due to spring will reach some very large value?

I had read that string responds instantaneously while spring takes a bit of time to act. Thus, by the time it's force gains any significant value, the collision will already be over.

Is my line of reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption is that the time taken for the collision is so short that the 1 kg mass does not move any measurable distance during this time and the spring is not compressed. With this assumption, momentum *immediately after* the collision is the same as momentum before the collision. As time progresses after the impact, the momentum of the blocks is *not* conserved, since the spring compresses and slows down the 1 kg block (if you consider the blocks *and* the Earth as a single system then momentum is still conserved, but that is not a very useful fact).